# Add Style tag to Twitter iframe

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

Hi i am trying to add a style tag into the head of the embedded twitter timeline so i can change some of the styling, i have written the css and added into a style tag. My plan was to inject this into the iframe using jquery however it doesnt seem to be working.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('#twitter-widget-0')
      .contents()
      .find('head')
      .append(
          '<style>div.css-1dbjc4n > section[aria-label="Timeline"] > div{display: grid !important;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}.css-1dbjc4n.r-140t1nj.r-qklmqi.r-1cbz2o1 {display: none;}.css-1dbjc4n.r-14lw9ot.r-1ets6dv.r-1q9bdsx.r-rs99b7.r-1udh08x {border: none;}.css-1dbjc4n.r-140t1nj.r-qklmqi {border: solid 1px #e3e6f0;border-radius: 10px;margin: 10px;box-shadow: 0 0.15rem 1.75rem 0 rgb(58 59 69 / 25%) !important;}</style>'
      )
  $('#twitter-widget-0').css('height', '600px')
  console.log("twitter styling bits")
}, 15000);
```

It finds the iframe and its id as the height changes to 600px however the style tage isnt added to the head?

---

Edit

The iframe is as follows (havent put the whole thing as its the twitter timeline and quite large) and i just want to insert things into the head tag.

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" class="" style="position:
    static; visibility: visible; width: 1092px; height: 600px; display: block;
    flex-grow: 1;" title="Twitter Timeline" src="...">

<html lang="en" dir="ltr" style="overflow-y: scroll; overscroll-behavior-y:none;">
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
</iframe>
```

Comment: You can't change anything inside an iFrame, it's an exact copy of the site. Think of it from a security aspect - if you created a copy of a banking website, it wouldn't be very good if you were able to edit aspects of it.

Comment: please share your iframe html

Comment: added the iframe in an edit, i was under the impression jquery could be used to inject things into an iframe (i have done it in the past?)

Comment: It can, if the iframe content is from the same origin. Which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not possible to manipulate the content of an iframe if you don´t have access to the iFrame source.